# FOLDINGCELL: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

Encountered this error while using FoldingCell pod in my swift project. I don't know how to solve this. Please help me. error here[image]

Answer (score -1):

The program found nothing. 'Nil' means nothing, so it's saying it found nothing when unwrapping the value.

Comment: how can I disregard the value "Nil"? to proceed on building my app?

Comment: try deleting and then redownloading the file